# process name (comm) as key for BPF map

Tags: ctypes, bpf, bcc-bpf, tracepoint

I've been trying to design a tool wherein I can do per-process tracing, but this implies that I need a key for each process so that I can store key-value map pairings for each process. I instinctually don't like using structs or strings as keys, and for a while I was considering how to access inode values for their use as keys. However there are numerous [examples](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/82f4302a651a6b46b0b090733d34af8201ecacb5/tools/lib/ucalls.py) that use structures or strings as hashmap keys, and Alexei suggested that process names will be [commonly used as a key](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/657623/). That said, I am unable to get a basic implementation of such a hashmap to work. Within the BPF program, the tracepoint isn't able to find the associated value with the process_name key. Perhaps I'm comparing memory locations and not the string literals as intended? Is there something going on under the hood with c_types that creates a mismatch between the keys?

```
from bcc import BPF
from bcc.utils import printb
from bcc.syscall import syscall_name, syscalls
from ctypes import *

b = BPF(text = """

struct procName {
    char name[16];
};

BPF_HASH(attempt, struct procName, u32);

TRACEPOINT_PROBE(raw_syscalls, sys_exit)
{
    u32 *val;
    struct procName hKey;
    bpf_get_current_comm(hKey.name,16);
    val = attempt.lookup(&hKey);

    if (val)
    {
        bpf_trace_printk("Hello world, I have value %d!\\n", *val);
    }

    return 0;
}
""")

class procName(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("name", (c_char_p*16))]

myFirst = procName(('p','y','t','h','o','n','\0'))
trialUpload[myFirst] = c_int(10)

while 1:
    try:
        (task, pid, cpu, flags, ts, msg) = b.trace_fields()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Detaching")
        exit()
    print("%-18.9f %-16s %-6d %s" % (ts, task, pid, msg))
```

Comment: What kernel version are you running? It could be the issue fixed by the patch you linked to.

Comment: 5.7.0-rc1 -- post patch

Comment: Upon further investigation, this seems to be an issue with how I implemented python's ctypes. I'll try to get to the bottom of it and post a solution

Comment: @pchaigno thanks for your help over the past couple weeks! I finished my first iteration and put together a pretty cool HIDS project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the original code has nothing to do with BCC & BPF and lies within my implemention of ctypes. For starters --

```
class procName(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("name", (c_char_p*16))]
```

creates a structure with the field "name". In the above definition, name will be of type *char[16] when I want a char[16]. Second, while this

```
myFirst = procName(('p','y','t','h','o','n','\0'))
```

might work, its not the best practice initialization. This is the correct approach --

```
class procName(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("name", (c_char*16))]

s = "python"

mySecond = procName()
mySecond.name = s
```

Thus, the full program incorporating a process_name based key and implementation of such to pass data from python is then..

```
from bcc import BPF
from bcc.utils import printb
from bcc.syscall import syscall_name, syscalls
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

b = BPF(text = """

#include <linux/string.h>

struct procName {
    char name[16];
};

BPF_HASH(attempt, struct procName, u32);

TRACEPOINT_PROBE(raw_syscalls, sys_exit)
{
    u32 *myVal;
    struct procName key;
    bpf_get_current_comm(&(key.name),16);

    myVal = attempt.lookup(&key);

    if (myVal)
    {
        bpf_trace_printk("values: %d\\n", *myVal);
    }

    return 0;

}
""")

class procName(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("name", (c_char*16))]

trialUpload = b["attempt"]

s = "python"

mySecond = procName()
mySecond.name = s
trialUpload[mySecond] = c_int(5)

while 1:
    try:
        (task, pid, cpu, flags, ts, msg) = b.trace_fields()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Detaching")
        exit()
    print("%-18.9f %-16s %-6d %s" % (ts, task, pid, msg))
```